# all characters double-wide when running xterm under arch linux in a virtual machine under VirtualBox using XQuartz in Mac OS X?

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux, xorg

Why are xterm fonts displaying all characters double-wide when running xterm under arch linux in a virtual machine under VirtualBox using XQuartz in Mac OS X?

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Here are my resources for xterm:

```
arch$ xrdb -query | grep -i xterm
XTerm*deleteIsDEL:      true
XTerm*backarrowKeyIsErase:      true
XTerm*faceName: foobar
XTerm*faceSize: 10.0
XTerm*renderFont:       true
XTerm*utf8Title:        true
XTerm*utf8:     always
XTerm*iconName: terminal
XTerm*JumpScroll:       on
XTerm*ScrollBar:        off
XTerm*TitleBar: on
XTerm*utmpInhibit:      on
XTerm*ttyModes: kill ^X erase ^?
XTerm*visualBell:       off
XTerm*eightBitInput:    on
XTerm*metaSendsEscape:  true
XTerm*geometry: 128x40
```